# What is this small L shaped bracket thing called?

Tags: hardware, brackets, drawers, terminology

I have a drawer that broke because the screw which held this little plastic piece was tightened too far and cracked it. Could someone help me identify it so that I can order another one?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like an L corner bracket/brace. Probably worth upgrading to a metal one if it would fit:

[Amazon product link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H5S122)

[image: L corner brace]

Comment: This is NOT the same brace; it is not off-centered like the plastic one the OP was inquiring about. I need one too, just like the OP's, and that is how I got here, looking for info on where to find it. But that metal one you provided will not work, as the screw holes are not in the same location as those of the plastic one. Thanks anyway...

Comment: Shopping advice is off topic here. The OP asked for the *name* of the object so they could do their own search for a replacement. That's not the same as "where can I find this specific part?" which would be closed if asked here.